# Dynamic or Generic Type Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, dynamic

I am stuck between `Array` type. What I want to do is to detect `Array` type runtime while entering values.

I have one custom class defining `UIPickerView` and I want to pass the `datasource` based on requirements that sometimes the values may be `String`, `Int` or `Double`. So definitely, I can't define like below because typecasting will be issue.

```
var arrFirstComponent = [Any]()
```

So I want a solution like when I pass `Int` value the `Array` type becomes `Int` and when I pass `String` it becomes `String` type array or anything.

Can anyone help me out in that? I have seriously no idea how to achieve it.

P.S. I have seen many answers which inherit protocols but I din't find worthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
class PickerView<T> {
    var arrFirstComponent = [T]()
    // Your picker view code
}

let intPickerView = PickerView<Int>()
intPickerView.arrFirstComponent = [1, 2, 4]

let stringPickerView = PickerView<String>()
stringPickerView.arrFirstComponent = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I am looking for!

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Happy to help :)

Comment: What about if I want to use in `UIViewController` property rather than a `class`?

Comment: You can make your `UIViewController` generic and provide a custom initialiser to create the `ViewController` object.

Comment: Ok got it! Thanks :)

Comment: One more error I am facing like, when I am returning value inside `titleForRow` I need to typecast to `String` everytime and for double it fails and getting crash. Any solution to this?

Comment: Rather than using typecasting use `String(describing: )` to convert the object into `String`.

Comment: Let me check with that! thanks for the instant help!